# React router how to render a new component inside an existing one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is tough to explain, but say I have a nav bar up top that contains all the main links. I click the models link from the navbar up top and it renders the models page down below. The models page contains thumbnails to different models. How can I get it so that clicking on the thumbnail for that model gets me to load that person's component in place of the models page?

Here's what I have so far. By the way I'm using React-router 3.0.5

App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import LeftPane from './LeftPane.jsx';
import RightPane from './RightPane.jsx';
import CenterPane from './CenterPane.jsx';
import TopPane from './TopPane.jsx';
import Models from './Models.jsx';
import Projects from './Projects.jsx';
import Contact from './Contact.jsx';
import Router from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { modelBucket: [] };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/modelcall'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('this is the axios call from models.jsx (the response) :', response);
      this.setState({modelBucket: response});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('this is an error from the axios call in models.jsx', error);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div>
            <TopPane />
          </div>

          <div className="container-fluid">    
            <div className="row content imageThumbMargin">
              <div> 
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => React.cloneElement(child,
                  { 
                    modelNames: this.state.modelBucket.data,
                    path: this.props.route.path
                  })
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Model.jsx:  (modelcard are the individual thumbnails)

```
import React from 'react';
import ModelCard from './ModelCard.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';

class Models extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { modelList: [] };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p className = "text-center">Models Page</p>
        {this.props.modelNames.map((model, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i} className = "imageThumbs col-md-2">
              <ModelCard key={i} model={model} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Models;
```

and ModelCard.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';

class ModelCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to={'/' + this.props.model.name}><div>
          <img src={this.props.model.imageUrl} />
          <p className="text-center imageMarginRight">{this.props.model.name}</p>
        </div></Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModelCard = ModelCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep your navbar 'on top' of the other components is to render a base route, and then nest your other routes inside of it:

```
<Route path='/'>
  <Route path='/modelcards' component={ModelCards} />
  <Route path='/modelcards/:id' component={Model} />
<Route>
```

You can then call `browserHistory.push('/modelcards/${id}')` and the param `id` will be available under this.props.params.id and you can render the appropriate card in the `render` function.  If you want to pass a lot of params and don't necessarily want to create a route for it, you can pass params in the push call: `browserHistory.push({ pathname:'/modelcards', params: { id: ..., title:... })`

Comment: Hello Stephen thanks for answering. As for your routes, where would I put that exactly? In the Modelcard.jsx or where the site routes are detailed?